# Update docker image in running deployment of oc console via oc commandline

Tags: docker, openshift

I have created a deployment in openshift via webconsle where I am deploying a docker image from docker hub. I have selected the latest image while creating a deployment in web console where my image looks like hub.docker.com/test/test1:latest. So, currently the latest image is with tag 1 and it is running smoothly in the openshift console in a node. 
Now for example I change my dockerfile and update the docker image in dockerhub with the latest tag 2 so what I am trying to do from a oc console is that I am trying to update the latest image in the openshift deployment to 2. I tried command oc rollout deployment name but it is giving me error that there is no deployment but I am still not sure about my command.

Any help and suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: When you run ```oc get deployments```, what does it return?

Comment: I got it solved by adding new image streams in the open shift console. Since the new image stream triggered was enabled so everytime I added now image from docker hub to image stream oc import-image imagestreamname I got the latest build in deployment.